Electron React application
I am trying to build my electron React App using electron forge but when it gets to
⠋ Preparing native dependencies it stops the process from continuing. please what can I do.
I did
npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli and
npx electron-forge import
and on running this npm run make, when it gets to this part and it stops
⠋ Preparing native dependencies

enter image description here
